# Update cart options in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

After looking through the Codeigniter docs you can update the cart as follows:

```
$data = array(
       'rowid' => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
       'qty'   => 3
);
$this->cart->update($data);
```

I have tried doing the following to update the options within the cart;

```
$data = array(
       'rowid' => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
       'qty'   => 3,
       'options' => array(
             'color' => 'red'
       )
);
$this->cart->update($data);
```

But it doesn't, I had a good look online but can't seem to find any solutions. Why does this not update the options?

Comment: Do you have a product in your cart? You have to `$this->cart->insert($data);` first before you can update it

Comment: Yes, and item (with the options) has already been added to the cart.